# Understanding Frightful Aura and Frightened tick down

Tags: monsters, conditions, pathfinder-2e, aura

I have a question concerning Pathfinder Second Edition:

From my understanding, when a creature enters the Lich's [Frightful Presence](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterAbilities.aspx?ID=17) aura, it has to roll Will save.

Because of the nature of [Frightened](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=19), every time the creature's turn comes, it ticks down by one.

So within two turns, the aura is completely without any effect for the next 8 turns. (Gain immunity for 1 minute).

For an example of why this is weird to me:
The party of adventurers made it down to the Lich's evil lair. Beyond the door, the Lich Xarxark the Terrible awaits. The adventurers are Frightened by the Lich's aura that permeates through the door. As the Rogue takes turns to unlock it, the Frightened value ticks back down to 0 and now the party is ready to face the Boss, undaunted.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The party is only affected when they enter the room

[Auras](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterAbilities.aspx?ID=5) are an emanations that require [Line of Effect](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=359). Because of this, the party would only be affected by [Frightful Presence](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterAbilities.aspx?ID=17) once they've successfully entered the room with the Lich.

As there is nothing in Frightful Presence that says otherwise, the Frightened condition does tick down at the end of their turns, potentially even reducing the Frightened condition shortly after receiving it.

That being said, Frightened 4 or even 2 is a significant penalty, nearly the same effect as reducing a creature's level by the value with how many things it affects and how Proficiency works. It makes it easier for the Lich to affect them with its spells and special abilities, and significantly impacts their ability to hit it for 2-4 turns.